# Separate data with different ID - mysql or phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm trying to separate different product category in a receipt so that I can have different query for the MAJOR category and the MINOR category using MYSQL.

**MAJOR** has an item code of **771013** and **MINOR** has an item code of **771012**. That being said, I also want to get the items that have been ordered in each check.

[image]

**Here is my desired output.**

[image]  [image]

I'm using MYSQL and PHPExcel on how to do this.
Can you give me hints on how to do my query? Is this possible with the formula of vlookup with PHPExcel?

Answer (score 0):

To get the items in receipts

```
SELECT receipts_body.receipt_id,items.id,items.title FROM receipts_body
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = receipts_body.item_id
ORDER BY receipt_id
```

To get the receipts with MAJOR category

```
SELECT receipts_body.receipt_id,items.id,items.title FROM receipts
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = receipts_body.item_id
WHERE receipt_id IN (SELECT receipt_id FROM receipt_body WHERE item_id = 771013)
ORDER BY receipt_id
```

To get the receipts with MINOR category

```
SELECT receipts_body.receipt_id,items.id,items.title FROM receipts
LEFT JOIN items ON items.id = receipts_body.item_id
WHERE receipt_id IN (SELECT receipt_id FROM receipt_body WHERE item_id = 771012)
ORDER BY receipt_id
```

Comment: can I know how you plot your table? I tried to change the values but no results were found.

Comment: I have a table `receipts_main` which stores the serial number of each receipt and the creation timestamp. Table `receipts_body` has a foreign key `receipt_id` which points to table `receipts_main` and stores the rows of each receipt with the help of a foreign key `item_id` which points to table `items`. The latter contains the ID of each item and its description.